# Linux WBEM client to pull event logs from Windows SCOM Server

Tags: linux, windows, unix

I was told by my UNIX team that a wmi/wbem client for Linux called WBEMCLI allows Linux to pull event logs from a windows server given that the right parameters are configured on the linux side.

Now the question rises:

Having a SCOM server in place, would linux be able to pull the logs from this one particular server and be able to differentiate the logs from every windows server they were collected from?

Or will linux think that the logs all originated from the windows centralized log server (SCOM 2012)?

Would there be a way to differentiate the logs?

Thanks

Comment: We got the idea from here: http://superuser.com/questions/174578/access-windows-log-files-from-linux/174647#174647

Comment: Is there a header or host name tag we can use to filter ?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/02e9d50a-de6c-49ce-8db2-400e3e333cfc/linux-wmi-wbem-client-to-pull-event-logs-from-windows-scom-server?forum=operationsmanagerunixandlinux#6287adac-7504-402c-9ff8-160d29b5993f